# koala batch request implmentation for the list of api calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I want to find all the feeds with comments an also the profile image of the the user who commented on the posts. I found that it can be done through batch request. Now i am doing like this which fires lots of API request.

```
@facebook = FacebookToken.find_by_id(token.id)
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@facebook.access_token)
@results = @graph.get_connections("me", self.content)
@results.each do |post|
     post['comments']['data'].each do |comment|
         commnentor_image = @graph.get_picture(comment["from"]["id"])
     end
end
```

How can i get these into a single batch request so that it will give me all the posts with comments with the commentor image.

Thank's

Comment: did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

The batch request will definitely speed up your queries, but I would consider looking at FQL as well - FB documentation states that an FQL multiquery is even faster than batch queries! Better yet, you can batch your FQL multiqueries....

You can try this for the batch (see the **[Koala Wiki](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Batch-requests)** for more info) :

```
@graph.batch do |batch|
   r = batch.get_connections("me", self.content)
   r.each do |post|
      post['comments']['data'].each do |comment|
         commnentor_image = @graph.get_picture(comment["from"]["id"])
     end
   end
```

Check out the [**FQL docs**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) for more info...

To get you started:

```
@graph.fql_multiquery(SELECT .....your FQL Query)
```